# How to integrate AppCenter SDK into Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: jenkins, unreal-engine4, visual-studio-app-center, unreal-engine5

I want to automate the process to build my ue5 project.
I want to use Jenkins and connect it to AppCenter for distributing my build.
In the case that AppCenter is not available for Unreal projects, what alternatives are out there?

Downloading the SDK repo